# Any way to skin the Filezilla UI?

Tags: windows, themes, filezilla

This is petty, I know. But Filezilla is so much nicer looking on Linux and Mac OS, and I presume it's due to the nasty Windows Redmondish inset dividers that are just there in the OS.

Is there any way to change Filezilla's UI to use a different "skin", or even to put it on GTK, in Windows 8.x?

On my system (Windows 8.1):
[image]

On a GTK environment (Ubuntu):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Well, yes... In FileZilla you can go to `Edit > Settings > Themes` and select a theme - like `OpenCrystal`.

You may also be able to use the `GTKPreferenceTool` available from the GTK+ for Windows Runtime Environment Installer - Theme package. Then you can Start > Run > Change GTK2 Appearance (your mileage may vary).

You can also take a look at the `resources` directory if you feel like creating your own (you can start by copying and existing theme, such as OpenCrystal and changing the icons and name in the xml.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I don't really care about the icons. It's the window dividers and style that are the offender. I presume that's not GTK by default, since Filezilla isn't a GTK app, like Pidgin or others ported from Linux to Windows.

Comment: Hm... in Win 8.1 you can decrease the `BorderWidth` and `PaddedBorderWidth` registry key values to 0 in `regedit` -  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`. That should help the situation somewhat (well, it will decrease the thick external border for all apps anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Humanuty theme from [Filezilla Humanity orange | GNOME-Look.org](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Filezilla+Humanity+orange?content=146163).

[image]

---

1. Download the 146163-humanity.zip.
2. Unzip and copy it to `/Applications/FileZilla.app/Contents/SharedSupport/resources` on Mac OS X 10.10.4.
3. Switch theme to **Humanuty**.
   [image]
4. Result of **Humanuty style** Filezilla.
   [image]

Comment: The question is asking how to get the Windows version to look like the Mac or Linux version. Making the Mac version look like the Linux version does not help the unfortunate Windows users who are stuck with this legacy Windows 2000-era hideous interface.